# Show modal on successful Ajax call problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After getting results back in an Ajax call I want to show a modal on my HTML page with the data returned by the Ajax call. That I can do, but the complication is that I have a spinning gif modal shown during any Ajax call via this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Code to show spinning GIF for any Ajax call
    $body = $("body");
    $(document).on({
        ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");    },
         ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }    
    });
});
```

I think this is preventing my showEntry modal as nothing happens in the UI. The Ajax call is invoked from a form submit button as follows:

```
$('#formsearch').click(function() {
    var  dataSet;
    // Send Ajax request to get results of search entry
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/searchreceive.php",
        data:{"c_year": contestYear, "bCode":barCode, "e_number": entryNumber} 
    }).done(function(status) {
        status = status.trim();
        if(status === "InvalidSession"){
            // Redirect to logout page
            window.location.href='../common/php/logout.php';
        }
        if(status === "NoResults") {
            alert("No record found - please try again.");
        } else {
            dataSet = JSON.parse(status);
            //console.log(dataSet);
            // Set modal form field values & display it
            console.log('About to show modal "showEntry" ...');
            $('#showEntry-modal-form').toggleClass('is-visible');  
        }
    }); 
});
```

(Note that in the code above I haven't yet looped through the dataSet to get the returned recordset to set the modal's input element values).

I tried moving the call to show the modal to be outside the Ajax call, but since it's asynchronous that doesn't seem to work.

**CSS**

```
    /* Start by setting display:none to make this hidden.
       Then we position it in relation to the viewport window
       with position:fixed. Width, height, top and left speak
       for themselves. Background we set to 80% white with
       our animation centered, and no-repeating */
.modalLoading {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    text-align: center;
    /*background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) */
    background: rgba( 248, 248, 248, .8 ) 
                /*url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') */
                url('<?php echo BASE_HDR_TAG . "contest/common/img/ajax-loader-red.gif"; ?>')
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}
/* When the body has the loading class, we turn
   the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
body.loading .modalLoading {
    overflow: hidden;   
}
/* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
   modal element will be visible */
body.loading .modalLoading {
    display: block;
}
/**
 * Modal window (process entry as paid))
 */
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.modal.is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
.modal-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    z-index: -201;
}
.modal.is-visible .modal-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6em;
    left: 50%;
    width: 30em;
    margin-left: -16em;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    z-index: -200;
}
.modal-transition {
    transition: all 0.3s 0.12s;
    /*transform: translateY(-10%);*/  /* transition fade In from top */
    opacity: 0;
}
.modal.is-visible .modal-transition {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.modal-header, .modal-content {
    padding: 1em;
}
.modal-header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.06);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
.modal-close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.modal-close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
.modal-heading {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.modal-content > *:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.modal-content > *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.modal-form {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.modal-form .form-group {
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 2.5%;
}
.modal-form .form-group1 {
    width: 95%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 3%;
}
.modal-form .form-group label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.modal-form .form-group1 label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.modal-form .form-control {
    line-height: 2;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
}
.modal-form .form-control2 {
    line-height: 2;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
}
.modal-form .form-control3 {
    line-height: 2;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 102%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
}
.modal-form .form-control::placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
}
.save-btn, .cancel-btn {
    border: 0;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.save-btn {
    background: #1391dd;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.cancel-btn {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+39+Extended|Oxygen+Mono|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Contest Entry Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="showEntry-modal-form" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-overlay modal-toggle-showEntry"></div>
        <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
            <a class="modal-close modal-toggle-showEntry" href="javascript:void(0)">&times;</a>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <form id="showEntryForm" name="showEntryForm">

                        <div class="modal-form">

                            <input type="hidden" id="showEntryID" name="showEntryID" value="">                        

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>First name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" maxlength="30" disabled value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Last name</label>                            
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" maxlength="30" disabled value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Mobile phone</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" disabled value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="100" disabled value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group1">
                                <label>Title or name of entry</label>
                                <textarea rows="2" id="model_name" name="model_name" class="form-control2" maxlength="100" disabled></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group1">
                                <label for="remarks">Remarks</label>
                                <textarea rows="4" id="remarks" name="remarks" class="form-control2" maxlength="100" disabled></textarea>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group1">

                                <div align="center">
                                    <p style="margin-top:10px">Is model SECURED to base?
                                        <input id="securedRadioYes" class="radiobtn" name="securedToBase" type="radio" value="Yes">Yes
                                        <input id="securedRadioNo" class="radiobtn" name="securedToBase" type="radio" value="No">No
                                    </p>                                    
                                </div>                            

                                <label for="category">Category</label>
                                <select class="form-control3" id="category" name="category" size="1" disabled></select>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group1" style="margin-top:30px">
                                <input type="submit" id="save" name="save" class="save-btn" value="Save"> 
                                <button class="cancel-btn modal-toggle-showEntry">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>        

    <div class="modalLoading"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**
After making the code change suggested by Sigma, I still don't see the modal but I do know the Ajax call is successful and returning the JSON info.

[image]

**EDIT 2**
Added more HTML which shows Bootstrap css/js

**EDIT 3**
It's definitely the Bootstrap links that are causing the problem. If I comment out the Bookstrap links, it works; if I uncomment them it doesn't.

Comment: Instead of using: $('#showEntry-modal-form').toggleClass('is-visible');   try to use $('#showEntry-modal-form').show(); or $('#showEntry-modal-form').modal('show');

Comment: Tried that but no change in behaviour - modal still doesn't show.

Comment: Are you sure the else is executing, do you see the console.log('About to show modal "showEntry" ...'); in your console?

Comment: Yes, I do see both the text you indicated and the JSON dataset. Updated my question with screenshot.

Comment: Try manually adding **is-visible** class to the model first and see if it is displayed. Then, add another log line as **console.log($('#showEntry-modal-form'));** and see if it correctly returns the model element, if it does, you can see the element in the console log, if not, the value of length property will be 0.

Comment: I added a button to show the modal and that doesn't work, so something else is going on. This code works on another page I have, the only difference being the script code is on the HTML page whereas here it's on a linked JS file. EDIT: actually, on the page where I have similar code that works I don't use Bootstrap css/js, whereas here I do. Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: I ended up implementing the modal using Bootstrap's built-in capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned your question into a working fiddle. In my example I used `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` as a dummy back end server. The following fiddle works, but I had to change it in a few points (`type` was changed from `'POST'` to `'GET'` and `dataType` was changed to `'json'`). I hope it can help you figure out, where the error in your page might be located.

```js
$body=$('body');
$(document).on({
   ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");    },
   ajaxStop:  function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }    
});

$('#formsearch').click(function() {
    // Send Ajax request to get results of search entry
    $.ajax({type:"GET",url:"http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/5",dataType:"json"})
     .done(function(d) {
         let n=d.name.split(' ');d.first_name=n[0];d.last_name=n[1];
         $('#showEntryForm input').each((i,e)=>{if(d[e.id])e.value=d[e.id]}); // put data into form elements
         
         $('#showEntry-modal-form').toggleClass('is-visible');  
    }); 
});
```

```css
/* Start by setting display:none to make this hidden.
       Then we position it in relation to the viewport window
       with position:fixed. Width, height, top and left speak
       for themselves. Background we set to 80% white with
       our animation centered, and no-repeating */
.modalLoading {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    text-align: center;
    /*background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) */
    background: rgba( 248, 248, 248, .8 ) 
                url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif')
                /* url('<?php echo BASE_HDR_TAG . "contest/common/img/ajax-loader-red.gif"; ?>') */
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}
/* When the body has the loading class, we turn
   the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
body.loading .modalLoading {
    overflow: hidden;   
}
/* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
   modal element will be visible */
body.loading .modalLoading {
    display: block;
}
/**
 * Modal window (process entry as paid))
 */
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.modal.is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
.modal-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    z-index: -201;
}
.modal.is-visible .modal-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6em;
    left: 50%;
    width: 30em;
    margin-left: -16em;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    z-index: -200;
}
.modal-transition {
    transition: all 0.3s 0.12s;
    /*transform: translateY(-10%);*/  /* transition fade In from top */
    opacity: 0;
}
.modal.is-visible .modal-transition {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.modal-header, .modal-content {
    padding: 1em;
}
.modal-header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.06);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
.modal-close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.modal-close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
.modal-heading {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.modal-content > *:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.modal-content > *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.modal-form {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.modal-form .form-group {
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 2.5%;
}
.modal-form .form-group1 {
    width: 95%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 3%;
}
.modal-form .form-group label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.modal-form .form-group1 label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.modal-form .form-control {
    line-height: 2;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
}
.modal-form .form-control2 {
    line-height: 2;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
}
.modal-form .form-control3 {
    line-height: 2;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 102%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
}
.modal-form .form-control::placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
}
.save-btn, .cancel-btn {
    border: 0;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.save-btn {
    background: #1391dd;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.cancel-btn {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modalLoading"></div>
<div id="showEntry-modal-form" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-overlay modal-toggle-showEntry"></div>
    <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
        <a class="modal-close modal-toggle-showEntry" href="javascript:void(0)">&times;</a>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <form id="showEntryForm" name="showEntryForm">

                    <div class="modal-form">

                        <input type="hidden" id="showEntryID" name="showEntryID" value="">                        

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>First name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" maxlength="30" disabled value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Last name</label>                            
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" maxlength="30" disabled value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Mobile phone</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" disabled value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="100" disabled value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group1">
                            <label>Title or name of entry</label>
                            <textarea rows="2" id="model_name" name="model_name" class="form-control2" maxlength="100" disabled></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group1">
                            <label for="remarks">Remarks</label>
                            <textarea rows="4" id="remarks" name="remarks" class="form-control2" maxlength="100" disabled></textarea>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group1">

                            <div align="center">
                                <p style="margin-top:10px">Is model SECURED to base?
                                    <input id="securedRadioYes" class="radiobtn" name="securedToBase" type="radio" value="Yes">Yes
                                    <input id="securedRadioNo" class="radiobtn" name="securedToBase" type="radio" value="No">No
                                </p>                                    
                            </div>                            

                            <label for="category">Category</label>
                            <select class="form-control3" id="category" name="category" size="1" disabled></select>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group1" style="margin-top:30px">
                            <input type="submit" id="save" name="save" class="save-btn" value="Save"> 
                            <button class="cancel-btn modal-toggle-showEntry">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>        
<input type="button" value="search" id="formsearch">
```

Comment: Yours works like a charm, and very similar to what I have on a different page. But what did you change (apart fromt he Ajax/JSON things)? And I think my problem is that I'm using Bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, this one runs without bootstrap. In fact I have no experience with bootstrap, so I can't help you there ...

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since you made it work with the original details provided. Plus, it's cool how you parsed the JSON dataset out to the HTML inputs.